# Move an object to a new page without Visio appending "1"

Tags: microsoft-visio

I've generated a Visio diagram from an Oracle database using the reverse engineering tool. ([This one](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54527), unless I've misunderstood. More on Visio version later.)

I want to move several objects to a different page than the one they were generated on. In particular, I want to preserve their relative positions.

To this end, I tried to use cut/paste, as there doesn't appear to be any other way to move objects across pages. Doing so, however, appends `1` to the object name.

How can I move the object to a new page without it getting renamed?

#### Demonstration of Cut/Paste Issue

Reverse engineering the database generated some tables and views in the diagram:

[image: Table created in diagram]

When I cut the table's shape, it removes it from the model:

[image: Table is removed from model when cut]

And then pasting it re-adds it, but with a `1` appended to the name:

[image: New table with 1]

Note that this happens even if the paste occurs on the *same* page.

#### Visio Version

I believe I'm using Microsoft Visio Pro for Office 365. That's what it says under "Subscription Product" when I go to File → Account, but if I click on About there, it just says "Microsoft Visio 2016 MSO." So I may be confused. (If someone could confirm my understanding, I'll clean this section up.)

Comment: This is the default behavior in Data Model Diagram. As displayed in Tables and Views window, you cannot import two same tables with same Table name.

Comment: @WinniL Not sure I understand. There's only one object with this name in the diagram, but it's renaming it anyway.

Comment: Yes, it is expected behavior. If you want to use this database table in new page. You can delete the original one, then use the Reverse Engineering to import the data again in new page.

Comment: @WinniL That would discard all the work I've done so far arranging elements, which is not acceptable. I mentioned the fact I want to move multiple elements and preserve their relative positions in the question. I honestly don't care whether it's "expected." It's still extremely poor behavior from the software and is causing me extra work I shouldn't need to do, so I'm interested in a way to do what I actually need instead of whatever broken idea of what I need Visio was built with.